# gfortran properly search for module files

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have a large Fortran code base, following is a simple demo to show my problem.
Let's assume I have this code structure

```bash
├── obj
└── src
   ├── mod.f90      # module file
   └── main.f90     # main program that uses the module file
```

I have two compiler in my system, `gfortran` and `ifort` and somehow I ended up in this following situation

```bash
├── obj
│  ├── mmm.mod    # compiled by gfortran
│  └── mod.o      # compiled by gfortran
└── src
   ├── mmm.mod    # compiled by ifort
   ├── mod.o      # compiled by ifort
   ├── mod.f90
   └── main.f90
```

Now if I try to compile the main code with `gfortran` as

```bash
gfortran -c src/main.f90 -o obj/main.o -J obj -I obj
```

it throws this error,

```bash
Fatal Error: File 'mmm.mod' opened at (1) is not a GNU Fortran module file
```

It seems that `gfortran` is trying to use `mod.mod` in `src` directory instead of `obj` specified by `-J` flag. The gfortran manual says

```
       -Jdir
           This option specifies where to put .mod files for compiled modules.  It is also added to the list of directories to searched by an
           "USE" statement.

           The default is the current directory.
```

which as I understand should use the `obj` directory for searching the `.mod` file, but it does not. It tries to use the one in `src` directory. Why is that? How do I force `gfortran` to use the directory specified by `-J` first, to look for the `.mod` files?

Comment: Works for me, assuming my example follows yours - including files that comprise a small but *complete* example would be really useful. What version of gfortran?

Comment: I did the test on the exact same thing I posted and got the error. `gcc version 9.4.0`

Comment: OK - managed to reproduce it now - small misunderstanding of where the files were located. Also with 9.4

Comment: Even if there is a way to avoiding looking in `src` first, the best thing when supporting multiple builds arguably is never to pollute your source structure with compiler artefacts, and to use build systems designed for this case. So that you don't get answers like "delete the ifort objects!" can you explain why you are wed to the idea of keeping incompatible build files in the way? (Also known as, if it hurts when you repeatedly bash your head against the wall, stop bashing your head against the wall instead of worrying about how to get the right padded wallpaper.)

Comment: The gfortran documentation simply says that the directory used with `-J` is added to the search path.  It does not indicate whether the drectory is prepended or appended to current search path.  It is likely appended such that the current working directory is searched prior to the added directory; thereby finding the ifort compiled module.  The simplest solution is to delete ifort produced files before running gfortran as the two obviously don't mix.

Comment: The error message in your question refers to `factorial.mod`, but this is not listed in your little directory/file structure diagram.

Comment: I get a similar error when making a mistake like runnung `scons` directly instead one of the wrappers setting the output directories. Tye solution is to always delete any module or object files that inadvertently appear in the source directory. They should not ever be there.